# Trying to replace ; with ASCII control characters in a txt file by using a cmd file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, unicode, ascii

I am trying to write a .cmd file to take a text file and add a string to the beginning of each line, replace all the semicolons with a ASCII control code 30 (RS), and end each line with a RS followed by a ASCII code 31 (US). When I put the RS and US in the file, notebook won't save it unless it is in Unicode, but when I try to run it in Unicode, it won't run.

Here is what I have that is not working:

```
@echo on > Convert.txt & setLocal enableDELAYedexpansion

set old=;
set new=▲
set bgnstr=@TESTSTATS▲▲▲
set endstr=▲▼

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (test1.txt) do (
set str=%%a
set str=%BGNSTR%!str:%old%=%new%!%endstr%
>> Convert.txt echo !str!
)
```

If I substitute any other characters for the RS/US, it does what I want it to do.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=* delims= "` defines a space as delimiter; together with the tokens `*`, this removes leading spaces (but not tabs); do you want that?

Comment: In the file that I am trying to convert, each string is on it's own line, so what I had was working.

Answer (score 2):

Your script should work as expected but `▲` and `▼` are not ASCII control codes:

```
▲    U+25B2    Black Up-Pointing Triangle
▼    U+25BC    Black Down-Pointing Triangle
```

Unfortunately, neither ASCII control code `30` (RS) nor ASCII code `31` (US) is visible here; therefore inserted next screenshot from hexadecimal editor. In next script, `bgnstr` variable is slightly shortened to keep next output from `mycharmap.bat` script in acceptable length.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set old=;
set "new="
set "bgnstr=@TS"
set "endstr="
> Convert.txt (
  for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in (test1.txt) do (
    set str=%%a
    set str=%BGNSTR%!str:%old%=%new%!%endstr%
    echo !str!
  )
)
```

[image: script in hexadecimal]

**Input/output**:

```
==> type test1.txt
a;b;c
d;e;f;
h;i;j

==> D:\bat\SO\39006271.bat

==> type Convert.txt
@TSabc
@TSdef
@TShij
```

ASCII control codes are invisible above in output from `type Convert.txt`; 
the `mycharmap.bat` script in next code and following screenshot show them. The `mycharmap.bat` script comes from this my answer at superuser.com: [Full description of Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> codes](https://superuser.com/a/1047961/376602)

```
==> for /F "skip=2 delims=" %G in ('type Convert.txt') do @mycharmap.bat "'%G'"
Ch Unicode    Alt?    CP    IME    Alt   Alt0    IME 0405/cs-CZ; CP852; ANSI 1250

 @  U+0040      64         …64…     64    064    Commercial At
 T  U+0054      84         …84…     84    084    Latin Capital Letter T
 S  U+0053      83         …83…     83    083    Latin Capital Letter S
    U+001E                 …30…           030    Information Separator Two
    U+001E                 …30…           030    Information Separator Two
    U+001E                 …30…           030    Information Separator Two
 h  U+0068     104        …104…    104   0104    Latin Small Letter H
    U+001E                 …30…           030    Information Separator Two
 i  U+0069     105        …105…    105   0105    Latin Small Letter I
    U+001E                 …30…           030    Information Separator Two
 j  U+006A     106        …106…    106   0106    Latin Small Letter J
    U+001E                 …30…           030    Information Separator Two
    U+001F                 …31…           031    Information Separator One
 @TShij
```

[image: printscreen]

Answer (score 1):

[JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404) explains what the arrow characters are and provides a working solution in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39007595).

I want to show you a way to generate the ASCII characters RS (`0x1E`) and US (`0x1F`) at run-time, so you do not need to embed them in the batch file with a hex. editor. The trick is to use `forfiles` and its capability to translate hex. character codes in the format `0xHH` appearing in the command string argument (for instance, `0x09` will be replaced by a tabulator character prior to execution of the command string); type `forfiles /?` in a command prompt window and read the description of the `/C` parameter. Note that this method does not work for all ASCII control characters.

So here is the code, containing several explanatory remarks (`rem`):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem /* Store RS and US characters in variables `RS` and `US`, respectively: */
for /F %%A in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo 0x1E"') do set "RS=%%A"
for /F %%A in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo 0x1F"') do set "US=%%A"

rem // The above generated characters are used here:
set "old=;"
set "new=%RS%"
set "bgnstr=@TS%RS%%RS%%RS%"
set "endstr=%RS%%US%"

rem // A single redirection is used to avoid multiple file accesses:
> "Convert.txt" (
    rem /* The option string has been modified in order to reflect every line
    rem    as it appears in the file; not that empty lines still get lost: */
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("test1.txt") do (
        set "str=%%A"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to not lose exclamation marks:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(%bgnstr%!str:%old%=%new%!%endstr%
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```